# Extract URLs (multiple lines) from texttable

Tags: bash, shell

My source:

```
+-----------+-------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| positives | total |      scan_date       |                                       url                                        |
+===========+=======+======================+==================================================================================+
|     4     |  65   | 2015-09-21 23:29:33  | http://thebackpack.fr/wp-content/themes/salient/wpbakery/js_composer/assets/lib/ |
|           |       |                      | prettyphoto/images/prettyPhoto/light_rounded/66836487162.txt                     |
+-----------+-------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     1     |  64   | 2015-09-17 19:28:50  | http://thebackpack.fr/                                                           |
+-----------+-------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     1     |  64   | 2015-09-17 08:44:16  | http://thebackpack.fr/wp-content/themes/salient/wpbakery/js_composer/assets/lib/ |
|           |       |                      | prettyphoto/images/prettyPhoto/light_rounded/                                    |
+-----------+-------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to extract the full URLs (Full URL in one line):

```
hxxp://thebackpack.fr/wp-content/themes/salient/wpbakery/js_composer/assets/lib/prettyphoto/images/prettyPhoto/light_rounded/66836487162.txt
hxxp://thebackpack.fr/
hxxp://thebackpack.fr/wp-content/themes/salient/wpbakery/js_composer/assets/lib/prettyphoto/images/prettyPhoto/light_rounded/
```

The multiple lines URL is my problem. I tried for example: `awk '{print $9}'`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: it would make more sense to adjust the sql your using to generate this output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*\\|[[:blank:]]*' 'NR<3 || NF<5{next}
   $2{if (url) print url; url=$5; next}
   {url=url $5}
   END{print url}' file
```

**Output:**

```
http://thebackpack.fr/wp-content/themes/salient/wpbakery/js_composer/assets/lib/prettyphoto/images/prettyPhoto/light_rounded/66836487162.txt
http://thebackpack.fr/
http://thebackpack.fr/wp-content/themes/salient/wpbakery/js_composer/assets/lib/prettyphoto/images/prettyPhoto/light_rounded/
```